# Can't run command prompt "Run as Admin"

Tags: windows-7, command-line

I'm not able to open an elevated command prompt in Windows 7 Ultimate. Previously I was able to open such a command prompt in one of the following ways:

- Start > type "cmd" then hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>
- Start > type "cmd" then right click "cmd" and select *Run as Administrator*.

However when I try this now I only get a normal command prompt without administrator rights.

Any ideas what could be wrong, and how I could fix it?

Comment: Are there any errors?

Comment: @splash  i want to open with admin privileges, that's why i m writing here...

Answer (score 4):

Try this on a normal command prompt:

`powershell -command "start-process cmd -verb runas"`

If the command still end up opening a normal command prompt, update your PC using `Windows Update`, then try again.

Comment: This works, and is a great workaround, but why oh why can't I run it via a right click "Run as Administrator"?

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works for me...However, other ways didn't work (since updating my windows to 20H something) although I am an administrator on my machine.